# Unmarshaling nested custom same-type JSON in Go

Tags: json, go, recursion

Given the following JSON

```
{
   "some": "value"
   "nested": {
     "some": "diffvalue",
     "nested": {
        "some": "innervalue"
     }
   }
}
```

which roughly translates to this struct:

```
type Envelope struct {
    some     string         `json:"some"`
    nested   InnerEnvelope  `json:"nested"`
}
```

where `InnerEnvelope` is: `type InnerEnvelope map[string]interface{}`

Running a simple `json.Unmarshal([]byte value, &target)` does not help here, because of the recursive type nature of the original JSON.

I do not know up front how deeply and under which keys the inner maps will exist, so I cannot declare the types upfront.

The idea is, that using `map[string]interface{}` as the type is not good enough, since I need the values in the `InnerEnvelope` to be somehow transformed & typed. Details are not important, but image, I need to cast every value inside the `NestedEnvelope` of a bool type as a string saying "true" or "false" as opposed of having an actual `bool` type.

I turned to `UnmarshalJSON` interface to solve this problem. I can easily do it at the top level like so:

```
func (m *Envelope) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var stuff noBoolMap
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &stuff); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for key, value := range stuff {
        switch value.(type) {

        case bool:
            stuff[key] = strconv.FormatBool(value.(bool))
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

But since the inner `json.Unmarshal` will already have inner maps parsed as `map[string]interface{}`, I would need to yet-again to traverse the inner maps, cast them to appropriate type and perform my value transformations.

So my question is: In this case, what is the way this would be approached in Go, and preferably do it in a single-pass?

The expected result of the JSON example above would be:

```
Envelope {
     some: string
     nested: InnerEnvelope {
       some: string {
       nested: InnerEnvelope {
         some: string
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: The short answer is yes, you need to cast the `interface{}` to a `string` or possibly another `map[string]interface{}` since as you have mentioned, you don't know the structure at compile time.

Comment: "I do not know up front .. under which keys the inner maps will exist, so I cannot declare the types upfront.
..using map[string]interface{} as the type is not good enough, since I need the values in the InnerEnvelope to be somehow transformed & typed."  Sounds like you have a contradiction there

Comment: I don't understand why you feel that you need a custom unmarshal method. Go supports recursive data types just fine: https://play.golang.org/p/v4hKMTpGSWu.

Comment: @Peter To clarify, the example should state `nested1`, `nested2` and so on, i will not know which keys the nested structures will be under beforehand. @Vorsprung: where do you see a contradiction?

Answer (score 1):

Given your json, you can do this:

```
type Envelope struct {
    Some     string         `json:"some"`
    Nested   json.RawMessage  `json:"nested"`
}
```

json.RawMessage is a rather hidden gem, and more people seem to go for the map[string]interface{}.

Using json.RawMessage will result in the nested json to be represented by this `RawMessage`, which you then can process again as a normal json (unmarshal it into Envelope).

This is more elegant than the map[string]interface{} approach.

Comment: I think this is getting close to what I am looking for. How would I apply recursion to this principle, i.e. : a) unmarshal top level, look for things that are RawMessage b) unmarshal found RawMessage fields such that any key that would be a map is unmarshaled as RawMessage again c) do the above to arbitrary depth & fields? This seems basic, but it sounds to me like I need to somehow define the types to unmarshal to dynamically.

Comment: Very late response however: Recursion is possible by just parsing the next json.RawMessage with the same struct and keep repeating this until you only have basic types left